# Quantum angular momentum addition of two particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

I am learning about the angular momentum addition rule. we have two particles, both with s=1/2 and L=0, and we need to find the total J of the system. We know that  J = J1+J2, J1-J2, so in our case J=1 or 0. For case 1, $$m_j = 1,0,-1$$ and for case 0 $$m_j = 0$$
The eigenstates are

$$|1,1 \rangle  = |1/2,1/2\rangle_1  \otimes |1/2,1/2\rangle_2 $$
$$|1,0 \rangle  = 1/\sqrt(2) *[  |1/2,-1/2\rangle_1 \otimes|1/2,1/2\rangle_2 +   |1/2,1/2\rangle_1 \otimes|1/2,-1/2\rangle_2]$$
$$|1,-1 \rangle  = |1/2,-1/2\rangle_1  \otimes |1/2,-1/2\rangle_2 $$

and finally
$$|0,0 \rangle  = 1/\sqrt(2) *[ |1/2,-1/2\rangle_1 \otimes|1/2,1/2\rangle_2 -   |1/2,1/2\rangle_1 \otimes|1/2,-1/2\rangle_2]$$

What I don't get is the physical difference between $$|1,0 \rangle $$ and $$|0,0 \rangle $$

I mean, both particles have opposite spin in both cases.
My question is ,what experiment could help us tell these two states apart ?
What came to mind is that |0,0> means that when we measure the spin in ANY axis, we get 0, while |1,0> means that it is 0 in the z axis and none 0 in the others. But how could this be true, for case |0,0> if i am certain about the measurement in one axis, lets say x, i an uncertain about the others. So how can i be sure that i wont get the same spin for both particles in the y axis thus getting a state
$$ |0,m_y =1\rangle $$

I feel that maybe |0,0> is entangled while |1,0> is not, but can only provide hand waving arguments for it.

I go the info from [here](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/%7Eldeldebb/docs/QM/lect15.pdf), as well as some handwritten notes from my professor(talking about a neutron and an electron, but give the same solution).
[image]
[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am not sure about the entanglement but I had the same doubt a few years ago. My professor said that you get 4 eigenstates and two J values and you have to club them together. You do it such that you preserve parity symmetry for a single J value. The major difference in |0,0> is that it is antisymmetric in particle exchange. One should check why parity needs to be conserved in these operations (raising and lowering of mj). So, physically you want to invent an experiment that involves this exchange and has a measurable effect. I don't know how to do this otherwise this would have been in ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two states are:

$$|0,0\rangle = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\big( |+-\rangle - |-+\rangle   \big) $$

$$|1,0\rangle = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\big( |+-\rangle + |-+\rangle   \big) $$

which are both combinations of simultaneous eigenstates of $\hat S_z^{(1)}$ and $\hat S_z^{(2)}$ with different eigenvalues.

The only difference between the total spin eigenstates is the relative phase of single particle eigenstates. That's it.

Since relative phase is entirely quantum mechanical, it's difficult to give "physical" reason that will satisfy classical intuition.

From images available on the internet, angular momentum addition is shown as:

[image]

the spin-1/2 is:

[image]

and spin-1

[image]

So for $|1,0\rangle$, the individual eigenstates are in-phase and add up to $S=1$, $S_z=0$, while out-of-phase is a complete cancelation. The latter case is straight forward, while in the former case, it's also straight forward to get $S_z=0$. To get the $S=1$, you just have to imagine the little cones tilted,. well.. in-phase, so they wind up in the disk representing $|1, 0\rangle$.  Not very satisfying, but it's pretty much all we got other than math.

Answer (score 0):

Several operators can help you check. They include
$$
S^2=S_x^2+S_y^2+S_z^2,
\\
S_\pm=S_x\pm \mathrm i S_y,
$$
where
$$
\vec S=(S_x,S_y,S_z)
=\vec S_1+\vec S_2
$$
is **total** angular momentum. You'll find
$$
S^2|00\rangle=0,\quad S^2|10\rangle=2,
\\
S_\pm |00\rangle=0,\quad S_\pm |10\rangle=\sqrt{2}|1(\pm1)\rangle.
$$
The physics is: a spin-0 particle and a spin-1 particle behave differently under rotation (element in $SU(2)$
). That's what the formulas mean.

You shouldn't regard the spins as vectors in real space, because they are not. But if you insist to, you can imagine a vector of length $\sqrt{j(j+1)}$ pointing in some direction. The projected length along any axis can take $(2j+1)$ discrete values $m_j=-j,\cdots,j$.

For $j=0$, the spin is just 0 and measurement along any axis turns out 0.

For $j=1$, there are three results, $m_j=0,\pm1$. If a measurement gives $m_j=0$, this mean the spin vector is perpendicular to your measure axis. The vector length is always $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I get the math and i can blindly follow it for the exam, but what is the physics behind it? if two particles are "spinning" in opposite directions, when are we in |0,0> and when in |1,0>?

Answer (score 0):

The state
$\newcommand{ket}[1]{\left|{#1}\right>}
\ket{1,0}$ is connected to $\ket{1,\pm1}$ by a rotation. If you have some carefully prepared $\ket{1,+1}$ systems, you can mix them into a superposition which includes $\ket{1,0}$ just by lying on your side and using that coordinate system instead.  In the absence of some preferred direction in space, such as a magnetic field, symmetry demands that $\ket{1,0}$ have the same energy as the other members of the $\ket{1,m}$ triplet.

Furthermore, because the singlet and triplet states have different symmetry under exchange, the selection rules which enforce parity conservation in electromagnetism will mean the singlet and triplet states participate in different transitions.